# Can't create db in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d with mysql docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I created a `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER : root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp1
      MYSQL_USER: wp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
    restart: always
```

And in `sql` directory, I put a `init.sql`.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wp2;
```

Then run `docker-compose up`.

In the log there is a entry for the init script.

```
mysql | 2020-04-08 02:17:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

But the database `wp2` is not created.

```
$ docker exec -it mysql bash
# mysql -u wp -ppass
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| wp1                |
+--------------------+
```

How can I create a database with mysql container init script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `wp` user doesn't have access rights on wp2.

Append to your sql file:

```
GRANT ALL on wp2.* to wp@'%';
```